# Mapreduce returns error when accessing to datanode on master machine

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I set up a Hadoop 2.4.0 cluster with three machines. One master machine is deployed with namenode, resource manager, datanode and node manager. The other two worker machines are deployed with datanode and node manager. When I run Hive query, the work fails and the error is

> 2014-06-11 13:40:13,364 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Exception running child : java.net.ConnectException: Call From master/127.0.0.1 to 
>   master:43607 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection >refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
>          at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>          at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:5>7)
>          at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImp>l.java:45)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>          at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:783)
>          at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:730)
>          at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1414)
>          at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1363)
>          at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:231)
>          at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getTask(Unknown Source)
>          at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:136)
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>          at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
>          at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
>          at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
>          at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:529)
>          at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:493)
>          at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:604)
>          at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:699)
>          at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:367)
>          at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1462)
>          at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1381)
>          ... 4 more

if I disable the datanode on master machine, everything works well. I'm wondering if it's allowed to deployed datanode on the master machine. Thank you for your kindly help in advance.

BTW, my /etc/hosts on the three machines are the same:

> 127.0.0.1       localhost
>
> 10.1.154.231    master
>
> 10.1.153.220    slave1
>
> 10.1.153.133    slave2

Answer (score 1):

Please set up passwordless ssh on your master **to itself**.

You can achieve this by

```
  cat ~/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2
```

Make sure the permissions are correct

```
   chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can "ssh localhost" or "ssh master" passwordless. Also master can ssh passwordless to all slaves and all slaves can ssh passwordless to master. I have authorized_keys instead of authorized_keys2 in my .ssh file. The permissions are 0640 for authorized_keys. I still have error

Comment: perfect.I'm sure I could not find this tip on this issue.my problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you may check if the namenode is started correctly on the master by checking logs at your yourhadoopfolder/logs/hadoop-[hadoop-user]-namenode-master.log

It is often caused by the hdfs is not formatted before. Run

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

Of course you will need to put your data to the cluster again.